# After installing Chrome Remote Desktop polkit permissions are all skrewed up

Tags: remote-desktop, policykit

After installing chrome-remote-desktop on Ubuntu 21.10 it seems to mess up polkit permissions. It asks for my password 3 times after logging in (color profiles, remote repositories, color management?), and it asks for my password when modifying NetworkManager in any way. I know how to solve the NM issue, but why should I be doing any of this all of a sudden? This has happened many times in the past after installing chrome-remote-desktop, and I avoided it for years, but I need it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why exactly this is necessary after installing chrome remote desktop, but if you want to get rid of it, you need to configure **polkit** to run certain actions with elevated privileges.
From what I understand you are searching for polkit configuration files (.plka, put under `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/*.d/`, or .conf, put under `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/`) like these:

<del>- allows any user to manage color profiles on their own (`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/02-allow-colord.conf`):</del> 


```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
 if ((action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device" ||
 action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile" ||
 action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-device" ||
 action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-profile" ||
 action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device" ||
 action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile") &&
 subject.isInGroup("{users}")) {
 return polkit.Result.YES;
 }
});
```

EDIT: I deleted this, because it can cause a **segfault error** to appear, according to this post: http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12043).

Instead, a pkla-file can be created that does the same job:

- allows any user to manage color profiles on their own (`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/45-allow-colord.pkla`):

```
[Allow Colord all Users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

- allows any user to refresh system sources (`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/46-allow-update-repo.pkla`):

```
[Allow Package Management all Users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

- *(might need this aswell)* allows any users to do network changes on their own, like joining vpn and such (`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pkla`):

```
[nm-applet]
Identity=unix-user:* # alternatively, to allow users of group netdev only: Identity=unix-group:netdev
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.*
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

Hope it helps someone - cheers!